# How to capture optional word in php regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match, preg-match-all

Contents are structured as below:

```
$contents = '1234    FIRSTNAME   LASTNAME    M     4321
1345    LASTNAME    F     4621
8223    FIRSTNAME   LASTNAME    M     4256;
```

I just want to extract first name or last name in array as below:

```
Array ( [0] => FIRSTNAME LASTNAME,
[1] => LASTNAME )
```

My code:

```
<?php

$contents = '1234    FIRSTNAME   LASTNAME    M     4321
1345    LASTNAME    F     4621
8223    FIRSTNAME   LASTNAME    M     4256';

$res = preg_replace('/([A-Z]{2,24})\s+([A-Z]{2,24})/', '$1 $2', $contents);


preg_match_all('/([A-Z]{2,24}?\s[A-Z]{2,24})/', $res, $result);

print_r($result[1]);
```

Comment: This looks like a tab delimited file, is this being generated by a computer? Something like https://3v4l.org/CrjP9 could work but if it is delimited I'd recommend http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Comment: Also `1234    FIRSTNAME   LASTNAME    M     4321
1345    LASTNAME    F     4621'
8223    FIRSTNAME   LASTNAME    M     4256;` is invalid, is that an example or your actual code?

Comment: Beside said comments, you don't need `preg_replace`. Go for one `preg_match_all`: `preg_match_all('/[A-Z]{2,24}(?:\s+[A-Z]{2,24})?/', $contents, $result);`

Comment: I accidentally added quote, removed now

Comment: thanks @revo, worked perfectly. I was just searching for optional match. You did it perfectly

Comment: @Debendra Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50009590/3832970) proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following regex with a mere `preg_match_all` function:

```
'~\b[A-Z]{2,}(?:\h+[A-Z]{2,})?\b~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2W7ODK/1).

**Details**

- `\b` - word boundary
- `[A-Z]{2,}` - 2 or more uppercase ASCII letters (replace with `\p{Lu}` and use `u` modifier to match all Unicode uppercase letters
- `(?:\h+[A-Z]{2,})?` - an optional sequence of

  - `\h+` - 1+ horizontal whitespaces (it seems the lastname and firstname are always on one line)
  - `[A-Z]{2,}` - 2 or more uppercase ASCII letters
- `\b` - word boundary.

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/OQJfHf):

```
$contents = '1234    FIRSTNAME   LASTNAME    M     4321
1345    LASTNAME    F     4621
8223    FIRSTNAME   LASTNAME    M     4256';
if (preg_match_all('/\b[A-Z]{2,}(?:\h+[A-Z]{2,})?\b/', $contents, $result)) {
    print_r($result[0]);
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => FIRSTNAME   LASTNAME
    [1] => LASTNAME
    [2] => FIRSTNAME   LASTNAME
)
```